# Is there a simple way to code multiple if conditions?

Tags: java

I have the below piece of code in Java.  I need to execute all of the if statements.Is there a better approach to code this.In each of the statement, I would then make a database call.

```
if (!keyAccntId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1") && !(segmentId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")) && !(regionId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1"))) {
    templateOrder.add("1");
}
if (!keyAccntId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1") && (segmentId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")) && !(regionId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1"))) {
    templateOrder.add("2");
}
if (!keyAccntId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1") && (segmentId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")) && (regionId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1"))) {
    templateOrder.add("3");
}
if (keyAccntId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1") && !(segmentId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")) && !(regionId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1"))) {
    templateOrder.add("4");
}
if (keyAccntId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1") && (segmentId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")) && !(regionId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1"))) {
    templateOrder.add("5");
}
if (keyAccntId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1") && (segmentId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")) && (regionId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1"))) {
    templateOrder.add("6");
}
```

Comment: i would turn this into a bitmask and use a switch on it.

Comment: The bitmask solution solves the immediate problem. But my gut feeling is that the actual *goal* is questionable. Maybe you should explain what the "templateOrder" is and what you're going to do with it (or was this just a placeholder for the actual database call?)

Comment: You don't need `equalsIgnoreCase` doe a number as it doesn't have a case, try just `equals("-1")`

Comment: BTW there is 8 possible outcomes, there is two outcomes which you don't have a number for.  If `segmentId.equals("-1") && regionId.equals("-1"))` you don't do anything.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey : Had copied only the above 6.The conditions do exist.

Comment: @Marco: The order defines the results of the conditions needs to be displayed in the mentioned order.

Comment: So depending on the configuration (of strings being "-1" or not) you add an element to a list, and later you check which element is contained in the list to make a decision? So, when, for example, the list contains `"2"`, what are you doing then?

Answer (score 16):

You could create a bitmask and switch on it:

```
public static final int KEY = 1;
public static final int SEGMENT = 2;
public static final int REGION = 4;

int value = 0;

if (keyAccntId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")) {
    value += KEY;
}
if (segmentId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")) {
    value += SEGMENT;
}
if (regionId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")) {
    value += REGION;
}
```

That gives you 8 possible values, which you can switch on:

```
switch(value) {
case 0:
    // All false
    break;
case KEY:
    // only keyAccntId is true
    break;
case REGION:
    // only segmentId is true
    break;
case KEY + REGION:
    // segmentId and keyAccntId are true
    break;
// So on
}
```

### edit

Added constants to improve readability

Comment: I gave you an upvote because this seems like a good direction to go in. But I can't help thinking this is a little hard to read. It would scale well, which is a nice feature.

Comment: Doesn't this just reorganize his option tree? It's helpful, but perhaps it's more helpful to clean things up visually for him..?

Comment: @Duncan I agree. One way to make it better would be to use constants for each item and use them with & in the switch (`values += Const.KEY` and `case Const.KEY & Const.SEGMENT` for instances)

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, that would be a vast improvement. Your answer might be easier to read if you included such code in it.

Comment: You want `KEY + REGION` or `KEY | REGION` as `KEY & REGION` is `0`

Answer (score 7):

A shorter version of @njzk2's answer using Java 7.

```
public static final int KEY = 0b001, SEGMENT = 0b010, REGION = 0b100;

int comb = (keyAccntId.equals("-1") ? KEY : 0) +
        (segmentId.equals("-1") ? SEGMENT : 0) +
        (regionId.equals("-1") ? REGION : 0);
switch(comb) {
     case 0:       /* none are true. */ break;
     case REGION:  /* only regionId is -1 */ break;
     // more combinations.
     case KEY + SEGMENT + REGION: /* all are -1 */ break;
}
```

Comment: I think you should calculate the `switch` value before the `switch` statement to make it a bit more readable.

Answer (score 2):

No "If", No "Switch". This 3 lines would cover all your cases:

```
 int val = keyAccntId.equals("-1")? 3:0;
 val += ((segmentId.equals("-1")? 1:0) + (regionId.equals("-1")? 1:0);
 templateOrder.add(val+1+"");
```

.

You may want to encapsulated the code, so it would end up being something like this:

```
public int getTemplateOrder(int keyAccntId, int segmentId, int regionId){
  int val = keyAccntId.equals("-1")? 3:0;
  return val + (segmentId.equals("-1")? 1:0) + (regionId.equals("-1")? 1:0) + 1;
}

//Usage
templateOrder.add(getTemplateOrder(keyAccntId, segmentId, regionId)+"");
```

.

For readability these are those 3 lines:

```
   int acc = keyAccntId.equals("-1")? 3:0;
   int seg = segmentId.equals("-1")? 1:0;
   int reg = regionId.equals("-1")? 1:0;
   int val = acc;

   //Construct the value currently being used on each If statement.
   val += seg + reg;

   //You've got the value, so instead of If/switch, just set it.
   templateOrder.add(val+1+"");
```

I hope it's not too obscure.

Regards.

Comment: Are you sure? I think when all conditions are false the resulting val will be 0 and it returns -1

Comment: Good catch! Let me fix that.

Comment: @SyamS What about now? I like it.

Comment: I was thinking of somthing like this. Ideally this solution is correct if the `templateOrder` had binary sequence. But as per the question the order is lost in case of 5. The condition for `templateOrder = 5` is treated as binary of 6 `(110)`. That is the issue. But +1 for the solution ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, however I think I'm missing the line you are referring to :(, is it the one for  templateOrder.add("5"); ?

Comment: Yes. In your case it returns 6. The problem is he doesn't have a condition `keyAccntId == -1 && segmentId != -1 && regionId == -1`

Comment: Thanks, fixed. I gotta start testing better.

Comment: WOW.. That was brilliant.. You are a genius.. Unfortunately I can do only one up-vote ;)

Comment: Oh my.. you just made me blush.

Answer (score 0):

To make things easier visually you could do something like this...

```
boolean keyTF = keyAccntId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1"), 
segmentTF = segmentId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1"), 
regionTF = regionId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1");

if (!keyTF  && !segmentTF  && !regionTF ) {
    templateOrder.add("1");
}
if (!keyTF  && segmentTF  && !regionTF ) {
    templateOrder.add("2");
}
if (!keyTF  && segmentTF  && regionTF ) {
    templateOrder.add("3");
}
if (keyTF  && !segmentTF  && !regionTF ) {
    templateOrder.add("4");
}
if (keyTF  && segmentTF  && !regionTF ) {
    templateOrder.add("5");
}
if (keyTF  && segmentTF  && regionTF ) {
    templateOrder.add("6");
}
```

The problem though is that you're dealing with a logical truth table, and you simply have to step through all of the possibilities. Since you're working with 3 separate variables there is no way to compress the code any further

```
FFF
FTF
FTT
TFF
TTF
TTT
```

you're actually missing the TFT case :)

Comment: It does not simplify. Maybe it's more readable, but this is not simplification. This does not answer to the needs.

Answer (score 0):

Only six of the possible combinations result in a call to `add` method.

We note that the `add` method only gets called once in the OP code, because the conditions in the if statements are mutually exclusive... if one of those evaluates as TRUE, the others will return FALSE.

To go old school with a logic truth table:

```
keyAccntId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1") |       F       |       T       |
segmentId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")  |   F   |   T   |   F   |   T   |
regionId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")   | F | T | F | T | F | T | F | T |
----------------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
templateOrder.add("1");           | y | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
templateOrder.add("2");           | - | - | y | - | - | - | - | - |
templateOrder.add("3");           | - | - | - | y | - | - | - | - |
templateOrder.add("4");           | - | - | - | - | y | - | - | - |
templateOrder.add("5");           | - | - | - | - | - | - | y | - |
templateOrder.add("6");           | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | y |
----------------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If the resulting values were "lined up" with the conditions better, then you could reduce the number of times the comparisons were done.

```
int n = 0;
if (keyAccntId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1") {
  n += 4;
} 
if (segmentId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1") {
  n += 2;
}  
if (regionId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1") {
  n += 1;
}
templateOrder.add(String.valueOf(n));
```

**NOTE:** the code above is NOT equivalent to the OP code. To make it perform the equivalent, we'd need to add a conditional test, so that the `add` method is not called when when n is 1 or 5, and to convert the value of `n` to the specified string argument value:

```
n    arg
---  ----
0    "1"
1    - 
2    "2"
3    "3"
4    "4"
5    -
6    "5"
7    "6"
```

The logic table would look something like this:

```
keyAccntId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1") |       F       |       T       |
segmentId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")  |   F   |   T   |   F   |   T   |
regionId.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")   | F | T | F | T | F | T | F | T |
----------------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
n += 4;                           | - | - | - | - | y | y | y | y |
n += 2;                           | - | - | y | y | - | - | y | y |
n += 1;                           | - | y | - | y | - | y | - | y |
templateOrder.add(arg);           | y | - | y | y | y | - | y | y |
----------------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```